# I have an error with the library google-maps-react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I have an error with the google-maps-react library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react). I am working with typescript and React and the component has required a prop that it is "google" and I don´t know what it is.

```
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMapContainerProps } from './IMapContainerProps';

export class MapFuncionando extends React.Component<IMapContainerProps, {}> {

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMapContainerProps> {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={this.props.zoomLevel}
            initialCenter={{ lat: this.props.latCenter, lng: this.props.lngCenter }}>
            <Marker position={{ lat: this.props.latMarker, lng: this.props.lngMarker }} />
          </Map>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const LoadingContainer = (props: any) => (
  <div>Fancy loading container!</div>
);

export default GoogleApiWrapper(
  (props) => ({
    apiKey: props.apikey,
    LoadingContainer: LoadingContainer,
    language: 'es'
  }
  ))(MapContainer);
```

I am calling this component with the next line:

```
<MapContainer apikey={'myapikey'} google={''} zoomLevel={15} latCenter={value1} lngCenter={value2} latMarker={value3} lngMarker={value4} />
```

And the error that I have is:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `google` of type `string` supplied to `Map`, expected `object`.
    in Map (created by MapContainer)
    in MapContainer (created by Party)
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col (created by Party)
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row (created by Party)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (created by Party)
    in div (created by Party)
    in Party (created by App)
    in main (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
```

It is supposed that the GoogleApiWrapper include this prop and the suposseted value for this prop is window.google, as the documentation said, but I don't what is it...

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs (and your error), the Google prop should be an object, apparently referring to the `window.google` object:

> If you prefer not to use the automatic loading option, you can also pass the window.google instance as a prop to your  component.
>
> ```
> <Map google={window.google} />
> ```

Comment: I try to do that, and this object doesn't exist. All the examples are done in JavaScript not with Typescript and in this examples they don't include anything...

Comment: That object wouldn't exist by default, it would have to be created by a library which you are importing, so I'd read over the docs again and be sure you're importing the correct files in the proper order.  Being a library for Google Maps, I'd expect it requires you have access to the Google Maps API and include the scripts specified [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).